# Store Facebook userID in database using Javascript SDK and C# code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook, web

I couldn't find anyone answer this specific question on how to store a Facebook userID (or any other information, like name, birthday,... ) in a SQL Server database.

I am using the Javascript SDK for Websites developed in ASP.NET provided on https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web/v2.2

I understand that Facebook lets you specify a scope and you can retrieve these values within the Java , but I need to somehow get the Facebook UserID from the person who is logged in the code behind (C#) to then store in the database.

I have read about using hidden fields, and tried to implement it to display it on a label, but the label remains blank...

See below

```
       function testAPI() {

            console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
           FB.api('/me', function (response) {
               console.log('Successful login for: ' + response.name);
               document.getElementById('status').innerHTML =
                 'Thanks for logging in, ' + response.name + '!';
               ValueHiddenField.Value = FB.response.id; }
           );


       }
```

and

```
             <asp:hiddenfield id="ValueHiddenField"
              value="" 
              runat="server" OnValueChanged="ValueHiddenField_ValueChanged"     OnLoad="ValueHiddenField_Load"/>
```

and in code behind:

```
    protected void ValueHiddenField_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lbl_test.Text = ValueHiddenField.Value;
    }
    protected void ValueHiddenField_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lbl_test.Text = ValueHiddenField.Value;
    }
```

Could someone tell me what I am doing wrong with hiddenfields... or if there are other methods of getting the userID and reaching it in code-behind. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure if you check you Browser console log you should find something similar to the following

> Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

Because of this piece of code `ValueHiddenField.Value = FB.response.id;`

The value is `response.id` not `FB.response.id`

That's most likely why your label is blank.

Comment: It actually showed "ReferenceError: ValueHiddenField is not defined"... I'm not sure what to do here.

Comment: It actually showed "ReferenceError: ValueHiddenField is not defined"... I'm not sure what to do here.